# Create a Python string from a native pointer without char buffer copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, cpython

Is it possible?

I'd like to have a lot of strings stored in a PyTorch/NumPy tensor (e.g. in fixed-size UTF-32 4-byte character) - could even be mmap'd from disk, and then to manipulate them with Python3 string APIs.

For maximum elegance, savings of Python objects, manual arena-like memory management (and out of pure curiosity), is it possible to create native Python strings from an underlying buffer without causing the buffer copy?

I found https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromKindAndData which somewhat ambiguously says `If necessary, the input buffer is copied and transformed into the canonical representation`. Will it actually copy the buffer or no (if the underlying byte format needs not transformation)? Is there any other way to achieve zero-copy? There is also https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_4BYTE_DATA

The most simplest question formulation is whether it's possible to convert a pointer to ASCII bytes to a Python string view over that buffer without any buffer copy (and thus being yourself responsible for memory management of that buffer).

A relevant blog post about cpython's internal string object layout: https://www.heurekadevs.com/a-brief-look-at-cpython-string

**UPD1:** my comment below after discussion with @mark-ransom:
Yes, it appears that `PyUnicode_FromKindAndData` will call `PyUnicode_New` and then `memcpy` into the `PyUnicode` object. So the question can be reformulated as: can we create an empty string object with correct codec info, and then just set its `data` and `size` fields? How can we do it using `ctypes`?

**UPD2:** If anyone is intrigued by the same question, I also created a GitHub issue in the cPython repo for discussion with Python devs: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/104689

Comment: There might be games you could play with the `ctypes` module but I don't think there's a way to create an actual `str` object without a copy.

Comment: Yes, it appears that `PyUnicode_FromKindAndData` will [call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1989-L1993) `PyUnicode_New` and then `memcpy` into the `PyUnicode` object.

I wonder if it's possible to somehow hack around and construct PyUnicode object without PyUnicode_New and use a different layout, then what I'm seeking it might be possible. So the question can be reformulated: how to write an equivalent to PyUnicode_New using just `ctypes`.

I'll update the question with this information!

Comment: A simpler way would be to create an empty string object with correct codec info and then to set its `data` and `size` to our own values?

Relevant files: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/unicodeobject.c

Comment: Even if you could place your own value into `data`, how would you prevent Python from trying to free that buffer when it destroys the string?

Comment: As I understood, Python allocates the char buffer array directly in the PyUnicode object (and the char data pointer points inside the object itslef). So I assume, the PyUnicode object would be freed, but if the char data pointer points elsewhere, the free call would not affect it. So my understanding is that Python frees the PyUnicode+chardata itself, and does not call free on the char data pointer field.

Comment: Aside from the issue of how to stop Python from trying to free your data buffer, you'd need a way to stop *other* code from freeing your data buffer while the *string* still needs it. The buffer protocol (which sunmy2019 suggested in your Github issue) has ways to handle this, and it should be what you use for this kind of use case, but trying to get `str` objects to handle this? No way. You'd have to change way too much of the `str` design, just to handle something that's better handled by other tools.

Comment: I think, the data existence question should be out-of-scope and left over to the manual lifetime/memory management. This is explicitly an unsafe API proposal with a niche usecase: where the `str` just is a view over an existing char buffer. I think within this frame, no `str` design changes are needed (as `str` dealloc deallocs only the object itself and does not touch the external buffer). I would propose that this functionality is named sth like `ctypes.create_string_view_unsafe(ptr, cnt, kind)` to underline the unsafety and need of manual buffer lifetime management (can be immortal buffer!)

Comment: I agree that this can be decided not worth the support burden in the GitHub issue, but at least from technical design, the approach seems workable, no? Maybe even can be done in Python using `ctypes.pythonapi` to call string object creation and then patch it.